# git: merging from upstream doesnt pull top commit

Tags: git, github

I have set 2 remotes in my local git repo, one to fetch from upstream and one to push my changes to(my fork of upstream).

Upstream has a 'main' branch. When I do :

```
git merge upstream/main
```

I expect all that is in upstream main branch to be pulled. To verify, I do:

```
git log -1
```

But to my surprise, I see that all commits except the one on top are pulled. Only when I rerun 'git merge upstream/main', that top commit from upstream is pulled.

I have double checked this, and behaviour is same always.

Surely, I am doing something wrong.

Any lead?

Comment: Did you fetch before doing the merge?

Comment: And you should shows us with commands and outputs (`git log --graph --oneline` of the bramches involved, `git status`, `git merge`, etc as needed).

Comment: "When I do `git merge upstream/main`
I expect all that is in upstream main branch to be pulled." But that is wrong, because `merge` and `pull` are not the same. `pull` might merge, but `merge` does not pull.

Answer (score 0):

`git merge` **never** downloads the most recent version from the remote server (github.com in your case) - it always uses the locally cached version. This cache is updated by `git fetch`, `git pull` and possibly other commands. If you want to update the cache **and** merge in a single command run `git pull upstream/main` instead of `git merge upstream/main`

Here is a possible explanation of your observations:

1. The remote version looks like this:

   ```
   * BBB <- main (on github)
   |
   * AAA
   ```
2. You run `git fetch`

   ```
   * BBB <- main (on github), upstream/main (on your machine)
   |
   * AAA
   ```
3. Someone adds one more commit to remote

   ```
   * CCC <- main (on github)
   |
   * BBB <- upstream/main (on your machine)
   |
   * AAA
   ```
4. You run `git merge upstream/main`
5. You see that the most recent commit was not included
6. Something runs `git fetch`

   ```
   * CCC <- main (on github), upstream/main (on your machine)
   |
   * BBB
   |
   * AAA
   ```
7. You run `git merge upstream/main` again

Comment: But then I must see none of the remote commits, isn't? But I see others commit, except top one. And that top commit was done hours back before I ran my command.

Comment: @Mandroid than it means the last time you (or your Integrated Development Environment) ran `git fetch` was some time between the last and second to last commit. Also: the commit could have been made on the machine of one of your colleagues "hours ago" but pushed to github much more recently - the commit timestamp reflects when it was created, not when it was pushed.